# Am I doing something wrong with my AMRAP routine?

Tags: training, hiit, interval-training, anaerobic

I like to exercise to improve my condition to improve my Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu. Said that I like to do some bodyweight exercises, Runs, swimming and HIIT.

Recently I notice on my Garmin my HIIT benefits are 2.5 aerobic and 0.6 anaerobic. I had 137bpm divided into the following zones:

- 0:00 (zone 5)
- 3:38 (zone 4)
- 10:58 (zone 3)
- 1:39 (zone 2)
- 0:35 (zone 1)

Basically not an anaerobic benefit. How do I exercise, normally I set my watch for 15min of AMREP and I pick 3 exercises and I do as many reps as possible.

I'm concerned I'm not doing it right. I believe I must keep more in zone 5.

Does someone have any tips for me?

Comment: We can't really answer this question without knowing what your actual workout is. What exercises are you doing, when do you switch between the three exercises, and how many reps are you doing for each exercise?

Comment: Why do you believe you should be more in zone 5?

Comment: @DarkHippo probably making the incorrect assumption that if he's doing maximal effort HIIT then his heart rate should be in the highest of these arbitrary zones, just because his effort is maximal.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information you provided, it seems like your HIIT workouts are not providing much of an anaerobic benefit, as indicated by the low amount of time you spend in zone 5 (the highest intensity zone). This may be due to a variety of factors, including the type of exercises you are doing, the intensity of your intervals, and the length of your rest periods.

To improve the anaerobic benefits of your HIIT workouts, there are a few things you can try:

-Choose exercises that are more demanding and require a lot of explosive power, such as jumping squats, burpees, or mountain climbers. These types of exercises will help you to develop your anaerobic fitness and improve your performance in Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu.

-Increase the intensity of your intervals by going faster, working harder, or adding more resistance (e.g. by using a weighted vest or adding more weight to your exercises). This will help you to spend more time in zone 5, and to get more of an anaerobic benefit from your HIIT workouts.

-Reduce the length of your rest periods between intervals. This will help you to maintain a higher level of intensity throughout your workout, and to spend more time in zone 5.

In addition to these tips, it may also be helpful to work with a coach or trainer who can help you to design an effective HIIT program and provide guidance on how to maximize your anaerobic benefits. They can also help you to monitor your progress and adjust your workouts as needed to ensure that you are getting the most out of your training.